# Cannot pass model attribute in thymeleaf th:each

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm trying to iterate over a list and pass the current iteration and another model variable to a fragment, but the "other" model variable is always null.

```
      <div th:each="place : ${results.placeResults}" class="col-sm-6 col-xl-4 mb-5">
        <div th:replace="fragments/placecard :: placecard" th:with="place=${place},res=${results}"/>
      </div> <!-- end for each-->
```

In the fragment `${res}` is always blank.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the `th:replace` basically makes the `th:with` have no effect.  I changed the code to use `th:include` and things look better.